# Avoiding save in a loop in mass action

Tags: magento2, best-practice, save, coding-standards, crud

I've created my own CRUD module that contains an inline edit action similar to the one for [CMS pages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/InlineEdit.php)
Everything works OK, but when running phpsniffer with the [EcgM2 standard](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/tree/master/EcgM2) I get this warning:

> Model LSD method save() detected in loop

**How can I avoid this?**
Note: The same warning appears if I "sniff" the core file linked above.
Here is my `execute` method in case someone needs it. But it's very similar to the one from the CMS page controller

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $error = false;
    $messages = [];

    $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
    if (!($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax') && count($postItems))) {
        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => [__('Please correct the data sent.')],
            'error' => true,
        ]);
    }

    foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $authorId) {
        /** @var \Sample\News\Model\Author $author */
        $author = $this->authorRepository->getById((int)$authorId);
        try {
            $authorData = $this->filterData($postItems[$authorId]);
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($author, $authorData , AuthorInterface::class);
            $this->authorRepository->save($author);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithAuthorId($author, $e->getMessage());
            $error = true;
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithAuthorId($author, $e->getMessage());
            $error = true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithAuthorId(
                $author,
                __('Something went wrong while saving the author.')
            );
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => $messages,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case you have to `save()` your entities, so you'll definitely have to call that method.

The native core Magento file you linked is not the only one that does that, especially the mass actions action classes.

The only alternative is to add a `saveAttribute` method to your CRUD resource model based on the one implemented in `app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute.php` :

```
public function saveAttribute(AbstractModel $object, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute instanceof AbstractAttribute) {
        $attributes = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    } elseif (is_string($attribute)) {
        $attributes = [$attribute];
    } else {
        $attributes = $attribute;
    }
    if (is_array($attributes) && !empty($attributes)) {
        $this->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
        $data = array_intersect_key($object->getData(), array_flip($attributes));
        try {
            $this->_beforeSaveAttribute($object, $attributes);
            if ($object->getId() && !empty($data)) {
                $this->getConnection()->update(
                    $object->getResource()->getMainTable(),
                    $data,
                    [$object->getResource()->getIdFieldName() . '= ?' => (int)$object->getId()]
                );
                $object->addData($data);
            }
            $this->_afterSaveAttribute($object, $attributes);
            $this->getConnection()->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->getConnection()->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This way, instead of calling the following:

```
$this->authorRepository->save($author);
```

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$author->getResource()->saveAttribute($author, array_keys($authorData));
```

As stated in the comments, you'll have to modify that method a bit if you don't need to check the `AbstractAttribute` instance to match your needs

Comment: Seams reasonable. thanks. I'll give it a shot and come back with the results.

Comment: @Marius just keep in mind that this method is slightly different than the EAV `saveAttribute` method as it accepts an array of "attribute codes" to save instead of just one attribute code

Comment: I've noticed that. I even modified it a bit so it won't accept and instance of `AbstractAttribute` as parameter, because I don't need it in my flat entity. It works smoothly. Thanks again.